# Using an Encounter Power with Combat Challenge? [Martial Power II]

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers

I'm currently building a Scimitar duelist fighter in 4e, and I'm using the Desert Moon Swordmaster Greater Style (MPII114). One of the benefits of this feat is that it allows you to use *dance of steel* (PHB79) in place of a melee basic attack when an enemy triggers your Combat Challenge feature.

My question here is: when that feature is triggered and I use *dance of steel* (or one of the other powers tied to that feat), is that power expended? Can I use it as a standard action again in the encounter? Can I use it again if the feature is triggered again?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the power is expended. All the feat does is provide you the option of using the *dance of steel* power instead of your melee basic attack.